# Alarm goes off on both AM and PM times

Tags: android, alarmmanager

starting my first real android app and I am having troubles setting the alarm for the correct time.  When using the time picker (and using the AM/PM buttons) it doesn't matter what you choose, it will go off on either/both.  I was able to extract which one the user uses as a string, but cant differentiate when trying to have the alarm tone go off.

Here is some of the code I've written:

```
//setting calendar instance with the hour/minute that we picked
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarm_timepicker.getCurrentHour());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarm_timepicker.getCurrentMinute());

//get the string value of the hour and minute
int hour = alarm_timepicker.getCurrentHour();
int minute = alarm_timepicker.getCurrentMinute();

//convert the int values to strings
String hour_string = String.valueOf(hour);
String minute_string = String.valueOf(minute);
String am_pm = "";
if (calendar.get(calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
    am_pm = "AM";
else if (calendar.get(calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM)
    am_pm = "PM";

if (hour > 12) {
    hour_string = String.valueOf(hour - 12);
}

if (hour == 0) {
    hour_string = String.valueOf(12);

}

if (minute < 10) {
    minute_string = "0" + String.valueOf(minute);
}

//method that changes hlp? status
set_Alarm_Text("hlp is on! " + hour_string + ":" + minute_string + " " + am_pm);

//put in extra sting into my_intent tells the clock, you pressed on
my_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm on");
```

Comment: `the alarm tone go off` you keep mentioning an alarm, but I don't see anything like that in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
 if(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0){
    am_pm = "AM";
 }else{
    am_pm = "PM";
 }
```

**AM** returns `0` value, while **PM** returns the value `1`

Comment: so what's the difference with the OP's code, beside being less readable?